# How to validate from the backend that the user is on free trial period?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I have enabled introductory offer for 3 days in my app store connect subscription.

But when i am validating the receipt data through backend everytime I am getting   [is_trial_period] => false
[is_in_intro_offer_period] => false

Why so?

[image]

I have created 3 day trial period with no end date.

but always getting response

```
Array
(
    [environment] => Sandbox
    [receipt] => Array
        (
            [receipt_type] => ProductionSandbox
            [adam_id] => 0
            [app_item_id] => 0
            [bundle_id] => com.askaguyfriend.lifecoach
            [application_version] => 17
            [download_id] => 0
            [version_external_identifier] => 0
            [receipt_creation_date] => 2024-02-06 07:54:57 Etc/GMT
            [receipt_creation_date_ms] => 1707206097000
            [receipt_creation_date_pst] => 2024-02-05 23:54:57 America/Los_Angeles
            [request_date] => 2024-02-06 07:56:19 Etc/GMT
            [request_date_ms] => 1707206179475
            [request_date_pst] => 2024-02-05 23:56:19 America/Los_Angeles
            [original_purchase_date] => 2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT
            [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1375340400000
            [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles
            [original_application_version] => 1.0
            [in_app] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [product_id] => annual_guyfriend
                            [transaction_id] => 2000000517700752
                            [original_transaction_id] => 2000000517700752
                            [purchase_date] => 2024-02-06 07:17:37 Etc/GMT
                            [purchase_date_ms] => 1707203857000
                            [purchase_date_pst] => 2024-02-05 23:17:37 America/Los_Angeles
                            [original_purchase_date] => 2024-02-06 07:17:44 Etc/GMT
                            [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1707203864000
                            [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2024-02-05 23:17:44 America/Los_Angeles
                            [expires_date] => 2024-02-06 08:17:37 Etc/GMT
                            [expires_date_ms] => 1707207457000
                            [expires_date_pst] => 2024-02-06 00:17:37 America/Los_Angeles
                            [web_order_line_item_id] => 2000000050727938
                            [is_trial_period] => false
                            [is_in_intro_offer_period] => false
                            [in_app_ownership_type] => PURCHASED
                        )

                )

        )

    [latest_receipt_info] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [product_id] => annual_guyfriend
                    [transaction_id] => 2000000517700752
                    [original_transaction_id] => 2000000517700752
                    [purchase_date] => 2024-02-06 07:17:37 Etc/GMT
                    [purchase_date_ms] => 1707203857000
                    [purchase_date_pst] => 2024-02-05 23:17:37 America/Los_Angeles
                    [original_purchase_date] => 2024-02-06 07:17:44 Etc/GMT
                    [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1707203864000
                    [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2024-02-05 23:17:44 America/Los_Angeles
                    [expires_date] => 2024-02-06 08:17:37 Etc/GMT
                    [expires_date_ms] => 1707207457000
                    [expires_date_pst] => 2024-02-06 00:17:37 America/Los_Angeles
                    [web_order_line_item_id] => 2000000050727938
                    [is_trial_period] => false
                    [is_in_intro_offer_period] => false
                    [in_app_ownership_type] => PURCHASED
                    [subscription_group_identifier] => 21426968
                )

        )

    [latest_receipt] => 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
    [pending_renewal_info] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [auto_renew_product_id] => annual_guyfriend
                    [product_id] => annual_guyfriend
                    [original_transaction_id] => 2000000517700752
                    [auto_renew_status] => 1
                )

        )

    [status] => 0
)
```